# - Broken pipe при попытке загрузить видео большого размера

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Есть метод:

```
startLesson: function(lesson) {
  var scope = this;

  scope.getLessonDataFromFile(lesson.id).then(function (data) {
    scope.mode = 'LESSON';
    scope.lesson.name = lesson.filename;
    scope.lesson.task = data;
    scope.lesson.taskHash = hash(JSON.stringify(scope.lesson.task));
    scope.lesson.flags = [];
    scope.lesson.score = [];
    scope.lesson.visibleDescriptions = [];
    scope.lesson.visibleDescriptionActions = [];
    scope.lesson.editMode = false;
    scope.lesson.analysisMode = false;
    scope.lesson.totalScore = 0;
    scope.lesson.maxScore = scope.lesson.task.timeslots.length * 15;
    $("#video")[0].load();
    $("#video")[0].addEventListener("canplay", scope.updateDurationOnCanplay, false);
 });
```

Когда этот код пытается загрузить видео, размер которого больше определённого значения (точное значение я ещё не определил, но это где-то в диапазоне 33-72 МБ), то происходит следующее:

```
[20/Jun/2016 15:24:18] "GET /lessons/api/lessons/01 HTTP/1.1" 200 6760
[20/Jun/2016 15:24:19] "GET /media/video/01.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 190267623
[20/Jun/2016 15:24:19] "GET /media/video/01.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 688128
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 217, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 328, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[20/Jun/2016 15:24:19] "GET /media/video/01.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 44686)
```

Мой API:

```
@staticmethod
def get(request, lesson_name):
    data_file_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_ROOT, lesson_name + '.json')
    data = {}
    try:
        with open(data_file_path, 'r') as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
    except IOError:
        data['timeslots'] = []
    data['id'] = lesson_name
    #data['filename'] = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, 'video', lesson_name + '.webm')
    data['filename'] = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, 'video', lesson_name + '.mp4')

    return Response(data)
```

Что тут не так?

Comment: Загрузить на сервер или скачать на клиент (браузер)? Что-то непонятно у вас из вопроса, в консоли GET повсюду. Ошибка проявляется на тестовом сервере или в процессе эксплуатации на продакшене?

Comment: @FeroxTL на тестовом. В продакшене всё работает.

Comment: Вообще это не очень хорошая практика - файлы через view отдавать, может попробовать куда-нибудь в media это всё деть, а в данном запросе лишь отдавать ссылку на скачивание полного файла (уже из media)

Comment: Вопрос еще актуален или решение уже найдено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможная причина ошибки в том, что

> используется `runserver`, который не предназначен для реального использования. Broken pip возникает, например, если, запрос со стороны браузера был внезапно прерван.
>   Решение проблемы: использовать вместо `runserver` что-нибудь предназначенное не для разработки, а для реального использования. Например [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/).

Цитата взята с ответа [Никиты Конина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181901/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Comment: Да, на продакшене был как раз `Gunicorn`, и все работало